Export every Sentinel 2 image over a region of interest, not just the median
I'm trying to export Sentinel 2 images over a region of interest from 2010 to 2020 and I require every image and not just the median.
I've tried using the following code :
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 20))
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2020-12-31');  // Keep all images within the date range

var rescale = dataset.map(function(image) { return image.divide(10000); });  // Apply scaling to each image
var clippedCollection = rescale.map(function(image) { return image.clip(roi); });  // Clip each image to ROI

Export.imageCollection.toDrive({
  collection: clippedCollection,
  description: 'sentinel_2010_2020',
  scale: 10,
  folder: 'your_folder_name', // Optional: Specify a folder within your drive
  maxImages: 1000 // Optional: Limit the number of exported images (if applicable)
});

but it's throwing an error -

Line 12: Cannot read property 'toDrive' of undefined"

Any solutions to this?

If you read the documentation, you will see there is no Export.imageCollection.toDrive function, you can only export images with Export.image.toDrive.  However, there is a third party batch script you can import with this functionality, try this answer on stackoverflow.
